# How to run oracle imp/exp from sql plus

Tags: oracle, import, export, command-prompt, sqlplus

I know `sqlplus` does not support exporting data in oracle.Using `EXPORT/IMPORT` utility is one of the method to export the data.`export/import` is a commant prompt utility.But is there any other way to export the schema from sql plus ? I am trying the below export command in command prompt and its working fine.

```
exp RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION/RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION PARFILE=exp01_rmc.par
exp RATOR_MONITORING/RATOR_MONITORING PARFILE=exp02_rm.par
```

Comment: You could use a [host](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1040156) command to call `exp` I suppose; but can you switch to data pump, and [use the API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#i1006610)? Or are you having to use the legacy export/import for some reason?

Comment: Actually i knw data pump but it requires some admin rights from client which i doesn't have and thts why not able to use. I am trying to find is it possible to do import/export of schema from sql plus

Comment: From sql developer i can export the schemas into sql file and simply run it from sql plus but it has some tablespace issues/buffer size issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SQL*Plus `host` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1040156) to run an operating system command:

```
SQL> host exp RATOR_MONITORING/RATOR_MONITORING@10.127.130.125/O2P00R11 PARFILE=exp02_rm.par
```

This assumes your operating system environment is set up properly; but since you're already running SQL*Plus successfully that shouldn't be an issue. You may prefer to create a shell/batch script to do the export, and call that from the `host` command instead.

Comment: Hello Alex now i understand. But do you have any example to create such shell/batch script for export and call it in the host command ? I have never tried before and requires to investigate more

Comment: @Rahul - you'd just put your `exp` command - optionally with environment setup if you might run it independently - into a text file; the file type depends on your OS (.bat for Windows, shell script for Unix/Linux); make it executable; and just use `host your_filename`. Creating scripts is not really relevant to the question you asked though, that's just a suggestion for simplifying things once it's working.

Comment: Ohh ok Alex now i understood.Thanks :)